# How to add external cpp libs to cmake project and pass to linker

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, linker-errors, libs

I have a project constructed from multiple git repos, I want to use some external open source libs in it (lets say lib1 lib2).

I have added the libs to the root cmake and to the subproject cmake:

root cmake:

```
find_package(lib1 REQUIRED)
find_package(lib2 REQUIRED)
```

subproj1/cmake:

```
find_package(Lib1 REQUIRED)
find_package(Lib2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(subproject1
        Lib1
        Lib2
        /path to dir contains Lib1 + Lib2 dir (see below)
        )
```

path contains:

```
/Lib1/:
Lib1Config.cmake
Lib1ConfigVersion.cmake
Lib1Targets-release.cmake
Lib1Targets.cmake

/Lib2/:
Lib2Config.cmake
Lib2ConfigVersion.cmake
Lib2Targets-release.cmake
Lib2Targets.cmake
```

when I build the project I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLib1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lLib2
```

even though in the clion-log:

```
./subproj1/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/clion-log.txt:57:-- Found the Lib1 static library: /path.../libLib1.a
Found the Lib1 shared library: path.../libLib1.so.1000.0.0
Found the Lib1 import library: Lib1_IMPORT_LIB-NOTFOUND
./subproj1/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/clion-log.txt:57:-- Found the Lib2 static library: /path.../libLib2.a
Found the Lib2 shared library: path.../libLib2.so.1000.0.0
Found the Lib2 import library: Lib2_IMPORT_LIB-NOTFOUND
```

Any idea why linker can't find the libs?

Comment: When you call `find_package(Lib1 REQUIRED)`, CMake actually executes the script `Lib1Config.cmake`. Usually, such scripts defines *target(s)* which you could link with. About which exact targets are created you need to consult the `Lib1Config.cmake` file or documentation for the project Lib1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it now works after I change the linkage to full path:

```
target_link_libraries(.../libLib1.so .../libLib2.so)
```

now sure why it works